# navigation2 - Set two scan topics to AMCL

Tags: navigation, ros2, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Env: ROS2 Foxy / Ubuntu 20.04

I have a robot navigating with two Lidars, so I have two topics /scan_front and /scan_back. in the costmap i am setting observation_sources: scan1 scan2, but how can I set two scan topics in the parameter "scan_topic" for AMCL ?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/378733/navigation2---set-two-scan-topics-to-amcl/) by [Youssef_Lah](https://answers.ros.org/users/41510/youssef_lah/) on ROS Answers with karma: 195 on 2021-05-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With the current state of AMCL this is impossible. You would need to build something that merges the 2 scans before providing them to AMCL as input.

I'd say that it's unlikely for AMCL to be extended with features like this, as within the nav2 community the main stream idea is to replace AMCL with something more modern. You can find more info here: https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/issues/1391

---

Originally posted by [Mbuijs](https://answers.ros.org/users/33718/mbuijs/) with karma: 247 on 2021-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1